# Symfony EmbedForm

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine, embed

Here is my situation, I have 3 tables: *student* | *attachment* | *student*_attachment_*link*

The student table is linked to the attachment table through a classRef relation to the linking table as is the Attachment table to the Student table.

```
relations:
Students:
  class: Student
  refClass: StudentAttachmentLink
  local: attachment_id
  foreign: student_id

relations:
Attachments:
  class: Attachment
  refClass: StudentAttachmentLink
  local: student_id
  foreign: attachment_id
```

So what is desired is to embed the attachment form into the student form so when editing a student I have the option to upload a new file (attachment)

I've gone through the documentation which has a fantastic example [Here](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms)

In this example they set up a subform and then tie the forms together by setting the current object to the new one being set up like this:

```
public function configure()
{
  $subForm = new sfForm();
  for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
  {
    $productPhoto = new ProductPhoto();
    $productPhoto->Product = $this->getObject();

    $form = new ProductPhotoForm($productPhoto);

    $subForm->embedForm($i, $form);
  }
  $this->embedForm('newPhotos', $subForm);
}
```

You can see in this example that    $productPhoto->Product = $this->getObject();
sets up the relation to be maintained

Now the secret from what I can tell is that this is a many to one relation however I have a many to many so I do the following:

```
  public function configure()
  {
      $attachment = new Attachment();
      $attachment->Student = $this->getObject();

      $form = new AttachmentForm($attachment);
      $this->embedForm('newFile',$form);
  }
```

This produces an error:
**Couldn't call Doctrine_Core::set(), second argument should be an instance of Doctrine_Collection when setting many-to-many references.**

I am clearly confused because I thought my object WAS a Doctrine_Collection, any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
Perhaps I am asking the wrong question or addressing a single point of failure that is only partially relevant. What I want to do is be able to Add/Delete an attachment from the student form and have it related to that student without having to customize the formAction and save() action. I have found that with Symfony 1.4 I can use:

```
$this->embedRelation('Attachments');
```

This work fantastically for editing for the most part I still need to work with it a bit, but I can't add or delete an attachment from the student form, which of course the desired outcome is to be able to completely control attachments from the student form i.e. add/delete/update an attachment.

Also any suggestions on a better way to do this are welcome, i.e. should I just have an "Add Attachment" link in my student form that takes me to the Attachment/new page, but if I do that how do I pass it the current student so that option can be automated...I have much to learn of this framework :-/

Comment: You can edit your post, can't you? If not I will do it for you. Now, as I told you, the example you are using is for a one-to-many relationship. Your form is about a single Student object,and you're trying to set a collection. It can't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would understand the problem quickly if you use proper naming for your relations:

```
relations:
  Students:
    refClass: StudentAttachmentLink
    local: attachment_id
    foreign: student_id

relations:
  Attachments:
    refClass: StudentAttachmentLink
    local: student_id
    foreign: attachment_id
```

Mark the "s"' . This is a many to many relationship. The example you are using is for a one to many relationship.

Comment: Is the above comment still true?

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answer you can't embed a form with many to many relationship, maybe you need to change the relationship to many to one because I don't think that one attachment belongs to many students, but if that is the case you can't embed attachment in student like the symfony documentation example, but you can follow this:

http://di-side.com/di-side/services/web-solutions/symfony-embedrelation-many-to-many-doctrine-relations/

if you change the relationship you can use this tutorial that include jquery functions for embed dinamically a form or a part of one into another

http://tech.cibul.net/embedded-forms-with-symfony-1-4-and-jquery/